# form values don't show up when posting to DOM

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form to create a mock blog post. When I submit the data it runs a function addPost, but the data does not show. The values are sent they just don't show on the DOM.

Here's my pen: https://codepen.io/unco0k3d/pen/rNedoRW

```
</>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first append the span, and the text to the cardBody before appending it to the main body div (or the div with the 'container' class in your case) in order for it to show up.

Basically always create from the bottom to the top element, for example if you want this structure:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Some text</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

you would first go about creating the span element and add the text to it, then the paragraph and append span to it and ultimately add the div and the latter paragraph to the div.

When you have that you can append div to the body (or in your case div with a container class)

Thing is that you didn't add any content to the div-body yet and you appended it to the container div and JS doesn't update the changes made to the div-body AFTER you already appended it to the container.
Simply don't append the element to any container until you have done all the actions on it that you want.